# Parse.com Installations - Times opened on device

Tags: swift, parse-platform

In Parse.com Data tab, there as an option for "Installations", where I can see info for all the devices that have installed and run my app.

How can I detect how many times the device has opened my application? I want to count each device, how many times it has opened my application.

Comment: Increment a count in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`

Answer (score 0):

Add a number to the installation class to increment/save whenever the app opens. This should be in `func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)` of the app delegate. This will also be called when the app is resuming from the background.

```
var installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
installation.incrementKey("appOpens")
installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
        println("appOpens incremented")
    } else {
        println("save error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
    }
}
```